# R create object name

Tags: r

The simple code below:

```
df01 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6), C = c(7, 8, 9))
```

Does not work when I tried this:

```
paste("df", "01", sep = "")
```

#> "df01"

```
paste("df", "01", sep = "") <-  data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6), C = c(7, 8, 9))
```

Error message is "target of assignment expands to non-language object"

What should I use to make it work?  I am using it in a for-loop.  Thanks!

Comment: Use `assign` : `assign(paste("df", "01", sep = ""), data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6), C = c(7, 8, 9)))`

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the fast response.